# ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following JavaScript error suddenly appeared:

> Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Comment: Are you including a key in your API include?

Comment: One thing I need to add is that in-addition to the api key, we will require to "Enable" the specific API, we are using, in the Google console too

Answer (score 124):

Yes. **Now Google wants an API key to authenticate users to access their APIs`**.

You can get the API key from the following link. Go through the link and you need to enter a project and so on. But it is easy. Hassle free.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Once you get the API key change the previous

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=your_api_key_here"></script>
```

Now your google map is in action. In case if you are wondering to get the **longitude** and **latitude** to input to Maps. Just pin the location you want and check the URL of the browser. You can see longitude and latitude values there. Just copy those values and paste it as follows.

```
new google.maps.LatLng(longitude ,latitude )
```

Comment: Helps me a lot.

Answer (score 78):

As per [**Google recent announcement**](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html), usage of the Google Maps APIs now requires a key. If you are using the Google Maps API on localhost or your domain was not active prior to June 22nd, 2016, it will require a key going forward. Please see the Google Maps APIs documentation to get a key and add it to your application.

Answer (score 20):

All Google Maps JavaScript API applications require authentication( API KEY )

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key.
2. Login with Google Account
3. Click on Get a key button
   3  Select or create a project
4. Click on Enable API ( Google Maps API)
5. Copy YOUR API KEY in your Project: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=(Paste YOUR API KEY)"></script>`

Comment: it works like a charm, yet do I need to **hide the api key**?  **Is your approach is going to be safe?**

Comment: @KickButtowski you should restrict your key by HTTP referrers or another way

Answer (score 1):

Update **django-geoposition** at least to version **0.2.3** and **add** this to settings.py:

```
GEOPOSITION_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
```

Answer (score 1):

The same issue i was facing couple of months back and that is because end of free google map usage effective from i think June 11, 2018. Google does not provide free google maps now. You need to have a valid API key and valid billing used, which may give you 200$ of free usage.

Refer link for more details: [Google map pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)

Follow the process [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key) to get your api key.

If you are upto using only maps with specific user, you can try other map tools.

Answer (score 0):

The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

See the guide to [API keys and client IDs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Comment: Copying the text straight from the documentation that is referenced by the error message is not useful at all.

Comment: agree with @pvgoran. don't just paste a link, show the relevant information from the link and just use it as a reference to the full text if the questioner wants to learn more

Answer (score 0):

you must create a project and collect the key in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en&key=()"></script>
```