# MissingKeyMapError that just began occurring with Google Charts + displayMode = text

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, charts, google-visualization

Same problem as described in [ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror), except that:

1. this is with Google Charts instead of Google Maps
2. unlike for Google Maps, there seems to be no documentation on how to get a key or use a key when it comes to charts / visualization (e.g. `var map = new google.visualization.GeoChart(...)`Googling "google charts MissingKeyMapError" yields NOTHING.
3. this error does not seem to occur if the html+js is served from a web server running on localhost. It only occurs when that html+js is saved to file and then the file is opened in a browser
4. this error only seems to occur when setting displayMode = 'text' (maybe in doing so Charts is calling Maps and I need to somehow pass some Maps API key inside there?)

This problem did not occur a couple of days ago. Googling "MissingKeyMapError charts" yields NOTHING.

Here's the code snipped that seems to recreate the error:

```
    var map = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map2-container')),
        map_options = {
          region: 'US',
          resolution: 'provinces',
          displayMode: 'text',
        };

    map.draw(stateText, map_options);
```

Any suggestions as to a workaround? Maybe some undocumented API options / hooks / etc?

========== UPDATE =============

I implemented the accepted answer as follows. There may be better ways than this:

```
<script>
  function init() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=drawMap&key=my_key';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages:["geochart"], callback: 'drawMap'});
  }

  function drawMap() {
    ...
    var map = new google.visualization.GeoChart(...)
    ...
  }
</script>

...

<body onload="init()">
```

Comment: I would suggest following the instructions on [getting an API key for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key), enable the Google Charts API (if it is available to be enabled).

Comment: that worked! thx. feel free to post and I will mark as answered with sample code solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions on [getting an API key for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key), enable the Google Charts API (if it is available to be enabled)

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing it for chart API and loading the packages using  google.charts.load(...), there is other way now. Set the version to '45' or 'upcoming' and also provide your API Key like this

```
  var myMapsApiKey = "some_apikey_you've_got_already";
  google.charts.load('45', { mapsApiKey: myMapsApiKey, packages: [ 'geochart'] });
```

I'm referring from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-visualization-api/bSyyqNruJ_k/pJkwMg0BCQAJ) and tested this working.