# Google maps API key error in any directory other than a certain

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use MAMP

Site in this directory - localhost/mysite

When i have error in console:

*"Google Maps API error: [MissingKeyMapError](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error) "*

I go to google api console, make new project, create new API key, insert this key in my site:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the error does not go away

I tried a bunch of options to create different keys activate different service api, making keys for the browser

Error on the map "Oops, something went wrong.." and "missing-key-map-error" do not go away

**UPD**

if I move the site to another directory

*localhost/mysite2/*

Then everything works as expected **without api key!**

Where API checks directory of where to work and where not?

Comment: See [ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror)

Answer (score 0):

As per Google recent announcement, http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html usage of the Google Maps APIs now requires a key. If you are using the Google Maps API on localhost or your domain was not active prior to June 22nd, 2016, it will require a key going forward. Please see the Google Maps APIs documentation to get a key and add it to your application.

**For more Detail**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

[ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror)