# MissingKeyMapError: Error while using Google Maps Autocomplete text box on local host

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying the below code for implementing Google Maps Autocomplete text box in HTML

HTML:

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
...
</head>

<body>
 ...
<input type="" name="loc" class="form-control" id="location" value="">
 ...
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
   function init() {
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
 </script>
```

The above code is working fine if I open HTML file in normal browser without using any server or local host. When I use the same code on local host, and click the text box, text box gets disabled automatically and throws the below error:

```
Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError  js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places:34
```

I was referring to this document [ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror) and it says usage of the Google Maps APIs now requires a key after June 22 2016. I created key and used the library as mentioned in the document https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key but had no luck as the textbox is not picking the library.

Tried below library replacing YOUR_API_KEY with the key generated for me:

```
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I use this library, it is not at all picking any location, and text box is showing empty.

I am getting this issue only when I use the Google API on a local host. Could someone help me how to get rid of this error? 
After generation of key, what is the exact library that should be used?

I am getting the below error after using the below two libraries:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry,places">
```

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? libraries=places&key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"
```

type="text/javascript">

Error:

```
Uncaught js?  libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAI_DaubDzVzYzVoVJ83Pc_KJAMd0HeNlQ&callback=initMap:95 InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

I am using the same javascript code as mentioned earlier.

Comment: related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 9975: Bug: Suddenly error occur for "Missing Key Map Error"](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9975)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include both the key (with localhost as an allowed referrer) and the places library.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

from [the documentation on libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries):

> The following bootstrap request illustrates how to request the google.maps.geometry library of the Maps Javascript API:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
> </script>
> ```