# Google Analytics DataChart: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: google-maps, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytic's Embed API to view my website analytics from a 3rd party site.  I am trying to visualize the geographic location of my viewers by city using the GEO chart option.  However, recently I began seeing the error:  MissingKeyMapError.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror) that Google is requiring an API key for Maps, and I have one, but how do I specify it for my geochart in Google Analytics Embed API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this problem.  All I did was include the Google Maps API library into the same page which utilized Analytics Embed API and included my API access code.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=A{ACCESS_CODE}&callback=callback"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```