# Call GoogleMap API in javascript file

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to call / load GoogleMap api in a javaScript file

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
```

I get the error message "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError"

I found this code using the tutorial here > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6wFYOtXwCQ&t=1s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991340/error-google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

This is needed to authenticate your application being the unique consumer of the API (only your application can use it...generally).

Just in case you need more information on how API keys work, this is a great resource: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key

```
script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap";
```

Where it says `YOUR_API_KEY` add the key.