# How to include GoogleMap in asp.net (WebForm)?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webforms

[image]

I tried include the GoogleMap into Asp.net Web form by using the codes from 
http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_many.

But when I run the codes, it shows the map for awhile and display the errormessage. Anyone can tell me what is the cause and how to solve it? 
Please enlighten me.

Comment: As the error message says please check the Javascript console. Without knowing what the exact error is people won't be able to help you. Also please add the code that you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403731/this-page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly-see-the-javascript-console-for-tech)

In other words, you should [obtain an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to be able to use the map, and set it in the code

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   @smirnov